# A C Project containing both C Code and Assembly Code

Tags: c

I have a sample project that contains C code and Assembly Code
There are `Main.c`, `Main.h` and `convert.S`.

Inside the assembly code `convert.S` there is the following code:

```
 .global
 .section .bss
 .section .text

 .global _FIL_2ORD                 
 _FIL_2ORD:
```

inside the convert.h file:

```
  extern int FIL_2ORD(
     tFIL2HISTORY *history;
     tFIL2COEFF *coeff;
     int input;
  );
```

Inside the Main.c function if it calls `FIL_2ORD();` then would it be resolved through the function inside the assembly code as declared in `convert.h` file?

My question is whether the assembly code would get compiled and linked, and whenever the `main.c` calls the function would it be referenced and resolved?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  It's certainly possible to call into assembly from C.  If you want an example, define a dummy function in C in a separate file and compile with 'gcc -S'.  Then look at the .s file that gcc produces.

Comment: Did you mean the main function when you wrote the "Main.c function"?

Answer (score 4):

Compile the C, assemble the ASM, and link the two together into an executable. The linker will find FIL_2ORD() inside the ASM's object file after it sees that the C's object file needs it.

The object files are created by the C compiler and the Assembler for each source file respectively.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is whether the assembly code would get compiled and
>   linked, and whenever the main.c calls the function would it be
>   referenced and resolved?

I'm assuming you're using the GCC compiler - Yes the `.global` directive in the assembly file makes the `_FIL_2ORD` symbol *public* to the linker, so it will become callable from outside the assembly source code.

This is an example of how you can compile, assemble and link using the command-line

```
gcc -o myexe Main.c convert.S
```

The `extern` declaration in `convert.h` is hinting the C compiler on what parameters the external function is expecting. The assembly source code should honor this declaration. You should look-up the standard C calling convention of your target platform to see the rules of how parameters are passed, and write your assembly code accordingly.

Depending on the target platform, the leading underscore char in the `_FIL_2ORD` declaration(inside `convert.S`) may or may not be necessary *(this is part of the platform-specific C calling convention I referred to in the previous paragraph)*. If the program fails to link, try again, this time removing the leading underscore.